# Real-time Monitoring of AWS Athena Queries from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena, aws-appsync

I am working on a serverless application using AWS Lambda (Node.js/JavaScript) and AWS AppSync. In my application, I use Athena to run queries on S3 files. I'm facing challenges in efficiently monitoring the status and obtaining real-time results of the Athena queries initiated from my Lambda function.

Here's a summary of my current implementation:

I trigger Athena queries using await athena.startQueryExecution(params).promise(); in my Lambda function.
I'm aware that checking the status of the query involves polling getQueryExecution until it's complete.
I'm looking for a more real-time approach or alternative solutions to monitor Athena query status and obtain results without constant polling.
Challenges:

Polling introduces delays, and I'm seeking a more real-time solution.
I've explored AWS Step Functions, CloudWatch Events, and Lambda Destinations but haven't found a satisfactory solution.
Objective:
I want to efficiently monitor the execution status of Athena queries initiated from my Lambda function and obtain real-time results without resorting to continuous polling.

Code Sample:

```html
const queryResults = await athena.startQueryExecution(params).promise();
```

Questions:

Are there alternative approaches or best practices for monitoring Athena queries in real-time from a Lambda function?
Is there a more event-driven solution that doesn't involve continuous polling?
How can I optimize the process to reduce delays in obtaining query results?

Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 1):

There is not such thing. AWS does not expose any API that you could use for this other than polling.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to trigger a processing Lambda on object creation within the S3 bucket

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).